# cannot find symbol "Embeddedrcall_Init"

Tags: c, r, g++, tcl, swig

I am trying to create a dll file using swig for an embeddedR C Program in windows environment. I am using the below commands:

```
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\Z>swig -c++ -tcl embeddedRCall.i
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\Z>gcc -c  embeddedRCall.c -I/swigwin-3.0.12/Examples/r/Z
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\Z>gcc -c  embeddedRCall_wrap.c -I/Tcl/include/tcl8.6 -I/swigwin-3.0.12/Examples/r/Z
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\Z>gcc -shared embeddedRCall.o embeddedRCall_wrap.o -o embeddedRCall.dll -L/Tcl/lib -L/R/R-3.3.2/bin/i386 -lR -lRblas -lRiconv -lRlapack -ltcl86
% load embeddedRCall
cannot find symbol "Embeddedrcall_Init"
```

I was able to load other example.dll files with tclsh
However I was unable to figure out the reason-- I am already using tcl 32 bit
My module file name is and module name is embeddedRcall
Am I missing something???
I am relatively new to TCL can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an exported (`extern "C"`) function symbol in your library called something like `Embeddedrcall_Init`; it is the entry point that lets Tcl install the library into a specific interpreter instance. (It has to be found explicitly because it takes an argument.) By default, the name of the function is found by munging the name of the library (strip version number, case convert, append `_Init`) but the determination of the name can be overridden by the *optional* [second argument to `load`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/load.htm).

To be more exact, if the entry is actually called `EmbeddedRCall_Init`, you would have to load it with:

```
load embeddedRCall EmbeddedRCall
# The _Init suffix is fixed when loading into a standard interp
```

Note the case difference! (Also, we recommend using fully qualified path names to loaded libraries, as it avoids some complexities in the `dlopen()` system.)

Comment: Even when loaded with load embeddedRCall EmbeddedRCall the same error is thrown. Am I missing anything. Please help me out to resolve the issue.