# Getting "cannot find symbol .... while executing load ..." error when trying to run Hello World as a C extension (dll) example

Tags: gcc, dll, tcl, mingw

I have used the C code from the following verbatim: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Hello+World+as+a+C+extension

```
 /*
  * hello.c -- A minimal Tcl C extension.
  */
 #include <tcl.h>

 static int 
 Hello_Cmd(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
 {
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj("Hello, World!", -1));
     return TCL_OK;
 }

 /*
  * Hello_Init -- Called when Tcl loads your extension.
  */
 int DLLEXPORT
 Hello_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
 {
     if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL) {
         return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     /* changed this to check for an error - GPS */
     if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "Hello", "1.0") == TCL_ERROR) {
         return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "hello", Hello_Cmd, NULL, NULL);
     return TCL_OK;
 }
```

My command for compiling is nearly verbatim except for the last character, indicating Tcl version 8.6 rather than 8.4, and it compiles without error:

```
gcc -shared -o hello.dll -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -I$TCLINC -L$TCLLIB -ltclstub86
```

Then I created the following Tcl program:

```
load hello.dll Hello
puts "got here"
```

But when running it with tclsh get the following error:

> cannot find symbol "Hello_Init"
>       while executing
>   "load ./hello.dll Hello"
>       (file "hello.tcl" line 1)

So I am essentially following a couple of suggestions from Donal Fellows answer here: [cannot find symbol "Embeddedrcall_Init"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43441934/34806)  The OP there however commented that, like me, the suggestion(s) hadn't resolved their issue.  One thing that I didn't try from that answer was "You should have an exported (extern "C") function symbol in your library" -- could that be the difference maker?  Shouldn't it have been in the example all along then?

At the suggestion of somebody on comp.lang.tcl I found "DLL Export Viewer" but when I run it against the DLL it reports 0 functions found :(  What am I doing wrong?

Could it be an issue with MinGW/gcc on Windows, and I need to bite the bullet and do this with Visual Studio?  That's overkill I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Can you report what `nm -g hello.dll` says?

Comment: It created 200 lines and 8k of output, it's out here: https://pastebin.com/dGkY1pe2

Comment: I am wondering: Is the DLLEXPORT macro expanded into sth. useful, e.g., `__declspec(dllexport)`? What about dropping-in `__declspec(dllexport)` instead, for a try?

Comment: @mrcalvin I'm totally new to this, where would I drop that in, as a replacement "int DLLEXPORT" just maybe not the "int" part?  OK I did that, made no difference, same error :(

Comment: `gcc -shared -o hello.dll -DDLLEXPORT=__declspec\(dllexport\) -DUSE_TCL_STUBS ...`

Comment: ... or change `int DLLEXPORT` in hello.c to `extern int DLLEXPORT`

Comment: @mrcalvin I tried all 4 permutations of your last 2 ideas, combined with the original ways, to no avail.  The tell-tale sign seemed to be that the dll was always the same exact size (47491) every time -- I might have expected a difference.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Could you post how you obtained MinGW (and Tcl) and the exact steps of running up to the lines above (in `cmd.exe` etc.) I could try to reproduce later today.

Comment: Well I got ActiveState Tcl the developer or complete install or whatever they call it.  I forget about MinGW though but at first I struggled because apparently it was not 64 bit but got that resolved.

Comment: Well, but there is MinGW and there is MinGW :) Pls. point me to the exact source of your downloads and the procedure you used to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is that your function `Hello_Init` is not ending up in the global symbol table exported by the resulting DLL. (Some linkers would put such things in as `_Hello_Init` instead of `Hello_Init`; Tcl adapts to them transparently.) The symbol *must* be there for Tcl's `load` command to work: without it, there's simply no consistent way to tell your extension code what the `Tcl_Interp` context handle is (which allows it to make commands, variables, etc.)

(If you'd been working with C++, one of the possible problem is a missing `extern "C"` whose *actual* meaning is to turn off name mangling. That's probably not the problem here.)

Since you are on Windows — going by the symbols in your DLL, such as `EnterCriticalSection` and `GetLastError` — the problem is probably linked to exactly how you are linking. I'm guessing that Tcl is defining your function to have `__declspec(dllexport)` (assuming you've not defined `STATIC_BUILD`, which absolutely should not be used when building a DLL) and yet that's not getting respected. Assuming you're using a modern-enough version of GCC… which you probably are.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  When I get this all worked out I will probably update the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also going through the process of how to build tcl extensions in C and had exactly the same problem when working though this same example using tcl 8.6.

i.e. I was compiling using MinGW GCC (64-bit), and used the following:

```
gcc -shared -o hello.dll -DUSE_TCL_STUBS "-IC:\\ActiveTcl\\include" "-LC:\\ActiveTcl\\lib" -ltclstub86
```

And like the OP I got no compile error, but when loading the dll at a tclsh prompt tcl complained :

> 'cannot find symbol "Hello_Init"'

I can't say that I understand, but I was able to find a solution that works thanks to some trial and error, and some information on the tcl wiki here
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Building+Tcl+DLL%27s+for+Windows

In my case I had to adjust the compiler statement to the following

```
gcc -shared -o hello.dll hello.c "-IC:\\ActiveTcl\\include" "-LC:\\ActiveTcl\\bin" -ltcl86t
```

Obviously those file paths are specific to my system, but basically

- I had to add an explicit reference to the .c file
- I had to include the `tcl86t` dll library from the tcl bin directory
- I had to remove the `-DUSE_TCL_STUBS` flag ( meaning that the references `-LC:\\ActiveTcl\\lib` and `-ltclstub86` could also be removed)
  (attempting to use the `-DUSE_TCL_STUBS` flag caused the compiler to complain with *C:\ActiveTcl\lib/tclstub86.lib: error adding symbols: File format not recognized* )

This successfully compiled a dll that I could load, and then call the `hello` function to print my 'Hello World' message.

Something else I stumbled over, and which wasn't immediately obvious:
reading https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/load.htm, tcl epxects to find an 'init' function based on a certain naming convention.
if the C extension does not define a package name then the name of that init function will be derived from the dll filename.
This caused a few problems for me (when compiling via Eclipse IDE), as the dll name was being automatically determined from the eclipse projet name.

For example, if  I recompile the same example, but call the .dll something else, eg.

```
gcc -shared -o helloWorldExenstion.dll hello.c "-IC:\\ActiveTcl\\include" "-LC:\\ActiveTcl\\bin" -ltcl86t
```

Then at tclsh prompt:

```
% load helloWorldExtension
 cannot find symbol "Helloworldextension_Init"
```